# How to load different layouts in a Recycler view with Single Adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Thanks for your time to read my question.
I have been working in a project where i have to load a lot of layouts in recyclerView.

To be detailed, Recycler list view to be contain of

- **-----Movies Layout -----(At the top)**
- **-----Theatres Layout -----( Below Movies Layout)**
- **-----Blockbuster -----(below Theatres layout)**

And I have designed like this,

- An activity with recycler view
- An CommonAdapter
- Three Pojo Classes
- Three layouts

The code i used,

My Pojo (All three pojo's are designed like same)

```
public class Movie {
    String title, genre, year;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getGenre() {
        return genre;
    }

    public void setGenre(String genre) {
        this.genre = genre;
    }

    public String getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(String year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public Movie(String title, String genre, String year) {
        this.title = title;
        this.genre = genre;
        this.year = year;
    }
}
```

**My RecyclerView Adapter**

```
public class MoviesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MoviesAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<Movie> moviesList;
    private List<Movie1> moviesList1;

    final int Movie = 0, Movie1 = 1;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView title, year, genre;

        public MyViewHolder(View view, int viewType) {
            super(view);
            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            genre = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.genre);
            year = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.year);
        }
    }

    public class MyViewHolder2 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView title, year, genre;

        public MyViewHolder2(View view, int Viewtype) {
            super(view);
            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            genre = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.genre);
            year = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.year);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        if (moviesList.get(position) instanceof Movie) {
            return Movie;
        } else if (moviesList1.get(position) instanceof Movie1) {
            return Movie1;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public MoviesAdapter(List<Movie> moviesList, List<Movie1> moviesList1) {
        this.moviesList = moviesList;
        this.moviesList1 = moviesList1;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v;
        MyViewHolder vh = null;

        // create a new view
        switch (viewType) {
            case Movie: //This would be the header view in my Recycler
                System.out.println("This is movie");
                v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.movie_list_row, parent, false);
                vh = new MyViewHolder(v, viewType);
                return vh;

            case Movie1: //This would be the header view in my Recycler
                System.out.println("This is movie1");
                v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.movie_row, parent, false);
                vh = new MyViewHolder(v, viewType);
                return vh;

            default: //This would be the normal list with the pictures of the places in the world
                return vh;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
       /* if (position == 0) {
            Movie movie = moviesList.get(position);
            holder.title.setText(movie.getTitle());
            holder.genre.setText(movie.getTitle());
            holder.year.setText(movie.getTitle());
            //this means it is beyond the headerview now as it is no longer 0. For testing purposes, I'm alternating between two pics for now
        } else if (position == 1) {
            Movie1 movie = moviesList1.get(position);
            holder.title.setText(movie.getTitle());
            holder.genre.setText(movie.getGenre());
            holder.year.setText(movie.getYear());

        }*/

        switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
            case Movie:
                MyViewHolder vh1 = (MyViewHolder) holder;
                Movie movie = (Movie) moviesList.get(position);
                vh1.title.setText(movie.getTitle());
                vh1.genre.setText(movie.getGenre());
                vh1.year.setText(movie.getYear());

                break;
            case Movie1:
                MyViewHolder vh2 = (MyViewHolder) holder;
                Movie1 movie1=(Movie1)moviesList1.get(position);
                vh2.title.setText(movie1.getTitle());
                vh2.year.setText(movie1.getYear());
                vh2.genre.setText(movie1.getGenre());

                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return moviesList.size();
    }
```

My Activity code

```
 recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        mAdapter = new MoviesAdapter(movieList, movieList1);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        prepareMovieData();
        prepareMovieData1();
```

And prepareMovieData() method code,

```
private void prepareMovieData() {
        Movie movie = new Movie("Mad Max: Fury Road", "Action & Adventure", "2015");
        movieList.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie("Inside Out", "Animation, Kids & Family", "2015");
        movieList.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie("Star Wars: Episode VII - The Force Awakens", "Action", "2015");
        movieList.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie("Shaun the Sheep", "Animation", "2015");
        movieList.add(movie);}
```

After running the program, Only first layout loads in my recycler view. Any help would be greatly helpful  for me to learn the stuff!

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

replace the `SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter` with a more `ComplexRecyclerViewAdapter` which does all the heavy-lifting for inflating different types of layouts based on the item view type.
for example your `RecyclerViewActivity` needs to contain a list of object as below:

```
private ArrayList<Object> getSampleArrayList() {
      ArrayList<Object> items = new ArrayList<>();
      items.add(new Movie ("Mad Max: Fury Road", "Action & Adventure", "2015"));
      items.add(new Theatres ("Something", "something"));
      items.add(new Blockbuster ("Something else", "Something else"));
      return items;
  }
```

after that you need three classes and layouts like MovieHolder.Java and movie_layout.java like below:
public class MovieHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

```
private TextView title, gener,year;

public MovieHolder (View v) {
    super(v);
    title= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
    gener= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.gener);
    year= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.year);
}

public TextView getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(TextView title) {
    this.title= title;
}

public TextView getGener() {
    return gener;
}

public void setGener(TextView gener) {
    this.gener= gener;
}

public TextView getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(TextView year) {
        this.label2 = year;
    }



}
```

and so on...

after that you need to create **ComplexRecyclerViewAdapter**

```
public class ComplexRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    // The items to display in your RecyclerView
    private List<Object> items;

    private final int MOVIE= 0,THEATERS=1 , BLOCKBUSTER = 2;

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public ComplexRecyclerViewAdapter(List<Object> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
           if (items.get(position) instanceof Movie) {
               return MOVIE;
         } else if (items.get(position) instanceof Theatrs ) {
               return THEATERS;
         }else if (items.get(position) instanceof Blockbuster ) {
               return BLOCKBUSTER ;
      }
         return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup   viewGroup, int viewType) {
              RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder;
  LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());

  switch (viewType) {
      case MOVIE:
          View v1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.movie_viewholder, viewGroup, false);
          viewHolder = new ViewHolder1(v1);
          break;
      case THEATERS:
          View v2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.theater_viewholder2, viewGroup, false);
          viewHolder = new ViewHolder2(v2);
          break;

      case BLOCKBUSTER :
          View v3 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_blockbuster, viewGroup, false);
          viewHolder = new ViewHolder3(v3);
          break;
      default:
          View v = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, viewGroup, false);
          viewHolder = new RecyclerViewSimpleTextViewHolder(v);
          break;
  }
  return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
               switch (viewHolder.getItemViewType()) {
      case MOVIE:
          ViewHolder1 vh1 = (ViewHolder1) viewHolder;
          configureViewHolder1(vh1, position);
          break;
      case THEATERS:
          ViewHolder2 vh2 = (ViewHolder2) viewHolder;
          configureViewHolder2(vh2, position);
          break;

      case BLOCKBUSTER :
          ViewHolder3 vh3 = (ViewHolder3) viewHolder;
          configureViewHolder3(vh3, position);
          break;
      default:
          RecyclerViewSimpleTextViewHolder vh = (RecyclerViewSimpleTextViewHolder) viewHolder;
          configureDefaultViewHolder(vh, position);
          break;
  }
    }
}
```

The following methods are used for configuring the individual `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` objects:

```
private void configureDefaultViewHolder(RecyclerViewSimpleTextViewHolder vh, int position) {
      vh.getLabel().setText((CharSequence) items.get(position));
  }

  private void configureViewHolder1(ViewHolder1 vh1, int position) {
      Movie movie= (Movie ) items.get(position);
      if (movie!= null) {
          vh1.getTitle().setText("Name: " + movie.title);
          vh1.getGener().setText("Gener: " + movie.gener);
          vh1.getYear().setText("Year: " + movie.year);
      }
  }
.
.
.
//and same for other 2
```

One final and important change before you can run the program would be to change the `bindDataToAdapter` method in your `RecyclerViewActivity` to set the `ComplexRecyclerViewAdapter` instead of the `SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter` as follows:

```
  private void bindDataToAdapter() {
      // Bind adapter to recycler view object
      recyclerView.setAdapter(new ComplexRecyclerViewAdapter(getSampleArrayList()));
  }
```

Comment: Thanks pal, What is RecyclerViewSimpleTextViewHolder in code mate?

Comment: its for catch unexpected values in switch statement.. you can ignore that or change it to handle your default action

Comment: you can change the code so getItemViewType() will return layout id of proper layouts and inside onCreateViewHolder() you can use that layout id for inflating

Answer (score 0):

First check the normal layouts and stuff is wired up properly or not see the xml code for the layouts.

My main suspect is getItemCount() method, you are returning only count of one list and i have seen many other implementations of multiple layouts in recyclerview most of them use single list and are setting some fields to null and in the onBindviewholder retrieve only fields that specific layout requires, hope this helps.

```
 List<CityEvent> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new CityEvent("London", null, CityEvent.CITY_TYPE));
    list.add(new CityEvent("Droidcon", "Droidcon in London", CityEvent.EVENT_TYPE));
    list.add(new CityEvent("Some event", "Some event in London", CityEvent.EVENT_TYPE));
    list.add(new CityEvent("Amsterdam", null, CityEvent.CITY_TYPE));
    list.add(new CityEvent("Droidcon", "Droidcon in Amsterdam", CityEvent.EVENT_TYPE));
    list.add(new CityEvent("Berlin", null, CityEvent.CITY_TYPE));
    list.add(new CityEvent("Droidcon", "Droidcon in Berlin", CityEvent.EVENT_TYPE));

 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    CityEvent object = mList.get(position);
    if (object != null) {
        switch (object.getType()) {
            case CITY_TYPE:
                ((CityViewHolder) holder).mTitle.setText(object.getName());
                break;
            case EVENT_TYPE:
                ((EventViewHolder) holder).mTitle.setText(object.getName());
                ((EventViewHolder) holder).mDescription.setText(object.getDescription());
                break;
        }
    }
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (mList == null)
        return 0;
    return mList.size();
}
```